# How to use minted package inside tabularx package

Tags: pdftex, tabularx, multicol, minted

I'm new to latex.
I'm having a `multicols` table. Below is the latex code -

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,graphicx,overpic}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\geometry{top=-0.5cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\pagestyle{empty} % Turn off header and footer

% \renewcommand\rmdefault{phv} % Arial
% \renewcommand\sfdefault{phv} % Arial

% Redefine section commands to use less space
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
    {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
    {0.5ex plus .2ex}%x
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
    {-1explus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
    {0.5ex plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
    {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
    {1ex plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\small\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % Don't print section numbers
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}

\definecolor{TableHead}{rgb}{0.353, 0.329, 0.667}
\definecolor{TableRow}{rgb}{0.816, 0.812, 0.902}

\NewEnviron{keys}[4][2]{% <-- Modified by default, 2 columns
    % \begin{center}
    \smallskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \rowcolors{1}{}{TableRow}
%    \centering
    \node (tbl) [inner sep=0pt] {
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{#1}{X}} % <-- Modified
        \rowcolor{TableHead}
        {\normalsize\textbf{\color{white}{#2}}}\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{0.3ex+\baselineskip}}
        & {\normalsize\textbf{\color{white}{#3}}}\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{0.3ex+\baselineskip}}
        & {\normalsize\textbf{\color{white}{#4}}}\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{0.3ex+\baselineskip}}
        \\
        \BODY
        \arrayrulecolor{TableHead}\specialrule{.17em}{0em}{.2em}
        \end{tabularx}};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[rounded corners=2pt,top color=TableHead,bottom color=TableHead, draw=white]
    ($(tbl.north west)-(0,-0.05)$) rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0.0,0.15)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=2pt,top color=TableHead,bottom color=TableHead, draw=white]
    ($(tbl.south west)-(0.0,-0.11)$) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)-(-0.0,-0.02)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \raggedright\
    
    \begin{center}
        \Large{\underline{Emacs Cheatsheet}}
    \end{center}
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        
        \begin{keys}[3]{Scenario}{Sample Code}{Explanation}
            Control (Ctrl) key  & \begin{minted}{python}
                import numpy as np
                
                def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
                m = len(genl1)
                n = len(genl2)
                M = None #to become the incidence matrix
                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
                
                #compute the bitwise xor matrix
                M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
                M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 
                ...
            \end{minted} & \texttt{C key for your OS} \\
            Alt (Meta) key      & \texttt{M} & \texttt{M Key for your OS} \\
            Shift key           & \texttt{S} & \texttt{M Key for your OS} \\
            Command (Super) key & \texttt{CMD} & \texttt{M Key for your OS} \\
            Function (Fn) key   & \texttt{fn} & \texttt{M Key for your OS} \\
            Home/end            & \texttt{fn-left / fn-right}  & \texttt{M Key for your OS} \\
        \end{keys}

        
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

This document is not compiling.

If I replace the below code with in the above latex document `\texttt{M}`, it will work fine.

```
        \begin{minted}{python}
                import numpy as np
                
                def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
                m = len(genl1)
                n = len(genl2)
                M = None #to become the incidence matrix
                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
                
                #compute the bitwise xor matrix
                M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
                M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 
                ...
            \end{minted}
```

The intention is to have multi line code inside a table column. How can I achieve the same?